# Beyond Face Reality(BRF) and C++ and VS2017

Tags: c++

I am currently using VS2017 with C++ to use the program of Beyond Face Reality(BRF).

Here is the link: https://github.com/Tastenkunst/brfv4_win_examples

However for some reason,I keep getting 3 error codes of LNK2001. Does anyone have any advice or answers to solve this?

int main() {

```
brf::trace("init app ...");

brf::CameraUtils camUtils(_imageDataWidth, _imageDataHeight, true);


if(!camUtils.init()) {
    brf::trace("No Camera found ...");
    return -1;
}

cv::namedWindow("main", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);

brf::Stats _stats;
brf::BRFCppExample example;

example.init(camUtils.cameraWidth, camUtils.cameraHeight, brf::ImageDataType::U8_BGR);

cv::Mat& draw = example._drawing.graphics;
cv::resizeWindow("main", draw.cols, draw.rows);

brf::trace("execute app ...");


while (true) {
    
    if(camUtils.update()) {
        camUtils.cameraData.copyTo(draw);
        example.update(camUtils.cameraData.data);
    }
    
    _stats.update();
    _stats.render(draw);
    
    cv::imshow("main", draw);
    
    int key = cv::waitKey(1);
    
    if (key == 27) { // 27 == ESC
        break;
    } else if(key == 114) { // 114 == R
        example.reset();
    } else if(key != -1) {
                    brf::trace("key: " + brf::to_string(key));
    }
}

brf::trace("dispose app ...");

example.dispose();

brf::trace("close app ...");

return 0;
```

}

## endif /* **GST_CAMERA_UTILS_H** */

Comment: You have appropriately set up your IDE / build system to link the library into your executable, see linked duplicate for explanation.

Comment: Hi,I followed according to https://github.com/Tastenkunst/brfv4_win_examples/issues/1 this page's instruction,but to no avail.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: ahh i see ok thanks ill edit